# Ending a sentence with an abbreviation

Tags: punctuation, abbreviations, sentence-ends

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Punctuation around abbreviations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/711/punctuation-around-abbreviations)

When a sentence ends with an abbreviation, should there be two periods or one?

> Welcome to ACME Inc. We are glad to have you on board.
>
> Welcome to ACME Inc.. We are glad to have you on board.

I would assume that only one is appropriate because I've *never* seen two used (and it looks awful), but if so, does the period "belong" to the **end of the sentence** or the **abbreviation**? I ask because I came across this while writing HTML, and the last word needs to be a link, so I wasn't sure if the period belongs within it.

> Welcome to [ACME Inc.](https://english.stackexchange.com/) We are glad to have you on board.
>
> Welcome to [ACME Inc](https://english.stackexchange.com/). We are glad to have you on board.
>
> Welcome to [ACME Inc.](https://english.stackexchange.com/). We are glad to have you on board.

Usually a link should not include punctuation at the end of the sentence, but *should* include it as the end of an abbreviation in the middle or beginning of a sentence. Which of these links seem more appropriate?

If only one period is used, who "owns" the period: the abbreviation or the sentence?