# Is the second period necessary after an abbreviation?

Tags: abbreviations, acronyms, periods, initialisms

Which one of the following is correct?

1. only in the continental U.S.A. For all other countries...
2. only in the continental U.S.A.. For all other countries...

I am not sure if I need two periods after "U.S.A." or just the one.

Comment: Welcome to the site. The answer depends on which style guide you follow. See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8382/when-etc-is-at-the-end-of-a-phrase-do-you-place-a-period-after-it and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/711/punctuation-around-abbreviations .

Comment: @choster I'm not aware of any style guide that permits a double period in this situation, and I didn't notice any in those other questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general consensus seems to be that there is never an acceptable use of two sequential periods. A period at the end of an abbreviation is adequate punctuation when a period would end the sentence naturally. If any punctuation mark other than a period is needed, that may be added. Similarly, within a sentence, as when a comma would be appropriate, that may be added.

Comment: Thanks John ! That's what I thought, but wanted to make sure !!

Answer (score 4):

> III.  only in the continental USA. For all other countries...

avoids the awkward lack of consistency of (1) and the awkward style of (2) - and is correct

(The United States of America (USA or U.S.A.)... : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States