# Is it okay to put a colon after an acronym?

Tags: lists, acronyms, colons

For example, when writing a list of fields to be filled e.g.

Name:
D.O.B.:
Address:

Is the colon after D.O.B. correct?

Comment: Surprisingly to me, [R H K Webster's](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/DOB) licenses DOB as a variant, and AHD doesn't mention other variants, while Collins says the use of full stops with the initialism is old-fashioned. DOB: looks tidier (and tidiness _is_ important in writing).

Comment: The rules are the same for colons as for semicolons and commas. Does this answer your question? [Punctuation around abbreviations](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/711/punctuation-around-abbreviations)

Comment: Note that most dictionaries would not regard DOB as an acronym as it is 'spelled out'. Compare BBC, IMF. Contrast NASA, AIDS, radar, which _are_ acronyms according to what most consider the default definition.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of *usage*, "it looks funny" is not a reason to use or avoid punctuation. The colon serves a purpose, and its proximity to the period has nothing to do with its purpose.

Typographic considerations might be different. If you don't like the visual appearance, you might consider using other symbols. Since these are not sentences, they don't *have* to use colons; underlines, m-dashes, etc. could be considered. One might also adjust kerning, letter spacing, or font until the effect is aesthetically pleasing.